# Restore Database from Database with Different Name

Tags: sql-server, restore

I have 2 databases, DB1 and DB2.  DB1 has production/live data.  A script runs daily (takes about 3 hours) to fill DB2.  The goal is to restore DB1 with DB2 so that DB1 is down for as little time as possible.  I've restored databases before but never from a differently named one.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to do something like a re-name swap?  Something like this:

1. Load DB2
2. Rename DB1 to DB_temp
3. Rename DB2 to DB1
4. Rename DB_temp to DB2

Then you re-load DB2 again the next time?

If so you can simply alter the name of the DB rather than deal with the time a restore takes (the file names will remain the same but that really doesn't matter in this case.)

```
ALTER DATABASE CurrentDBName MODIFY NAME = NewDBName;
```

Now on the other hand if you actually want to keep DB2 in place and just restore over DB1 it would look something like this:

```
RESTORE DB1 FROM DISK = 'DB2 backup file' WITH REPLACE
```

There are several methods you can use to improve your speed.  Probably the easiest is to stripe your backup.

```
BACKUP DATABASE DB2 TO DISK = 'loc1', DISK = 'Loc2', DISK = 'Loc3' WITH FORMAT
RESTORE DB1 FROM DISK = 'loc1', DISK = 'Loc2', DISK = 'Loc3' WITH REPLACE
```

Warning, you will need to have all of the files you stripe to in order to do your restore.  If you lose one the whole backup is useless.

Answer (score 0):

In the restore you just give the db, mdb, and log different names.  And there is an option to force - I think it is called replace.  We do this all the time to create new test db.